# How to insert multiple column in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, html-table, create-table

I want insert 2 column to database [artikel & pengarang], when I save that form it will be insert `$data` from to table artikel and $data to table pengarang [IDArtikel from Artikel &nama_pengarang].

This is my artikel SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `artikel`(
`IDArtikel` INT(11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`IDJurnal` INT(11)NOT NULL,
`IDKategori` INT(11)NOT NULL,
`judul` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`abstract` text NOT NULL,
`nama_file` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`dilihat` INT(50)NOT NULL,
`didownload` INT(50)NOT NULL,
`created_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`created_by` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`updated_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_by` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`IDArtikel`))ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

and this is pengarang SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `pengarang`(
`IDPengarang` INT(11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`IDArtikel` INT(11)NOT NULL,
`nama_pengarang` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`IDPengarang`))ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

this is my view:

```
<h3><?= $title; ?></h3><?php echo form_open("admin/artikel/buat/"); ?>
<table width="95%">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Pilih Referensi Jurnal</b></td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="IDJurnal" id="IDJurnal" value="<?php echo $IDJurnal; ?>" />
            <input type="text" name="volume" id="volume" value="<?php echo $volume; ?>" readonly="readonly"  class="sedang" />
        <?php echo anchor_popup('admin/artikel/popup', 'Referensi Jurnal', array('class' => 'button')); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Kategori</b></td>
    <td>
        <?php
            echo form_dropdown('IDKategori', $kategori) . "";
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="125"><strong>Judul</strong></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="judul" class="panjang"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="125"><strong>Pengarang</strong></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="pengarang" class="panjang">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Abstract</b></td>
        <td>
        <?php
            $data = array('name' => 'abstract');
            echo $this->ckeditor->editor($data['name']);
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Simpan">
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Batal" onClick="javascript: history.go(-1)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
            echo form_close();
?>
```

this is my controller:

```
function buat() {
    if ($this->input->post('judul')) {
        $this->MArtikel->addArtikel();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Artikel telah di buat !');
        redirect('admin/artikel/index', 'refresh');
    } else {
        // konfigurasi ckfinder dengan ckeditor
        $this->load->library('ckeditor');
        $this->load->library('ckfinder');
        $this->ckeditor->basePath = base_url() . 'asset/ckeditor/';
        $this->ckeditor->config['toolbar'] = 'Full';
        $this->ckeditor->config['language'] = 'en';
        $this->ckfinder->SetupCKEditor($this->ckeditor, '../../../asset/ckfinder/');

        $data['title'] = "Tambah Artikel";
        $data['main'] = 'admin/artikel/artikel_buat';
        $data['jurnal'] = $this->MJurnal->getJurnalDropDown();
        $data['kategori'] = $this->MKategori->getKategoriDropDown();
        $this->load->vars($data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/template');
    }
}
```

and this my model

```
function addArtikel() {
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $data = array(
        'IDJurnal' => $this->input->post('IDJurnal'),
        'IDKategori' => $this->input->post('IDKategori'),
        'judul' => $this->input->post('judul'),
        'abstract' => $this->input->post('abstract'),
        'created_time' => $now,
        'created_by' => $_SESSION['username']
    );

    $this->db->insert('artikel', $data);
}
```

form in pengarang, can insert multiple data

Comment: is it not working. Tell us whats the problem

Comment: you can use $this->db->insert_batch($array); have a look here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert

Comment: codeigniter insert multiple table in one function

Comment: when i used $this->db->insert_batch($array); it will be just update 1 table in my database

Comment: Why not create a model for pengarang add the addArtickle method to it and then call it in your controller?

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look at $this->db->insert_batch();](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)

Comment: can we used $this->db->insert_batch('mytable1','mytable2' $data); ??

Comment: no. you can use $this->db->insert_batch('mytable1', array $data1) and then $this->insert_batch('mytable2', array $data2)

Comment: what it would be like this in my model $data1 = array(
        );

        $data2 = array(
        );
        $this->db->insert_batch('artikel', $data1);
        $this->db->insert_batch('pengarang', $data1);

Comment: Yes where $data1 = array(array('field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => 'value2'), array('field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => 'value2')); The method will take each array from $data1 and will make a $this->db->insert()

Answer (score 0):

create new function in model `addPengarang` add the following code in your model, and change the values of data array as per your requirement it will insert values in Pengarng table

```
function addPengarang() { 
   $data = array(
        'IDPengarang' => 'value for IDPegarang',
        'IDArtikel' => 10,
        'nama_pengarang' => 'value for nama pengarang'
    );

    $this->db->insert('pengarang', $data);
}
```